# Laravel 5.1 testing with PHPUnit and PHPSpec

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, laravel-5, phpspec

Laravel 5.1 have been released. But I don't know how to use it's testing features because I'm still new with TDD stuffs.

For example, I want to test my Eloquent Model (relationships etc.) Anyone could explain with clear explanation? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing

Comment: Check this nice tutorial: http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-testing

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of type of testing we have in the world, What I would suggest you do is to write a unit test, for example, let's say you have users and posts table and you want to test the relationship.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$post = factory(Post::class)->create(['user_id'=>$user_id]);

$this->assertEqual(1, $user->posts->count());
```

This way you have tested the relationship between user and posts.